# My app was suspended due to an issue with ads

Tags: android, android-viewpager, google-play, admob, google-play-services

today **Google** suspended my app saying that my ads violated **Google** TOS but I don't know what did it actually violate. I think there might be something wrong with my code structure i guess because I tried publishing it two times and in both it got suspended.

In my app I am using a **View Pager** and inside it I have 4 tabs. So the ads are placed in the View Pager as below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" >
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

and the code in the **View Pager activity**

```
 mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I would be very thankful if someone told me the reason behind the continuous suspension.

Comment: According to the new google policy, Google has banned the ads in notification and on home screen, refer to the doc (http://phandroid.com/2013/09/30/google-play-notification-ads-policy/).

Comment: @vibhor-chopra Thanks for your reply. in fact, i didnt add ads in notification or on home screen, its just in the normal activity.

Comment: And where in your View Pager activity are you calling AdView.loadAd()? If you are doing it on every swipe that could be a problem.